# \section in \put

Tags: sectioning

I want to move title of section into left margin of page. Meanwhile, the first line of paragraph aligns with the title(not below title as usual), as shown on the following picture. I trid by putting \section in \put, but failed to compile. Anyone can help me with this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{picture}
\begin{document}
some text
\put(-1in,0){\section{my section content}}first line of paragraph
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure you can use units in the coordinates, and if you put the section in a minipage it works. `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
some text

\noindent\put(-4,0){\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\section{my section content}
\end{minipage}}

first line of paragraph
\end{document}`

Comment: Thank you very much! It does work though I don't understand why `parbox` can not replace `minipage` in my example. And as shown in my attached figure, "some text" and "fist line of..." should be in two lines. But as the effect of `\put`, they are in the same line. So I add `\par` after "some text", then fails to compile. Why?

Comment: Maybe `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
some text
\reversemarginpar
\marginpar{\section{my section content}}

first line of paragraph
\end{document}`?

Comment: Yes, \marginpar is a good idea. Yet it's difficult to control the horizontal position of section title. I love better your solution of minipage. Now I'm puzzled by failing work of "some text\par"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using titlesec's `leftmargin` pre-defined format as it was designed for this purpose (see section 3.1 of titlesec docs). Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
{\normalfont\bfseries\filleft}
{\thesection.}{.5em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}
{4pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1pc}

\begin{document}
    \section{my section content}
    First line of paragraph
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: output]

Edit - A second example with an even wider margin and a 'hang' (following question in comment):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For filler text
\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
{\normalfont\bfseries\filright}% Now right justfy
% 'hang' hack - put some negative space before section number
% Now with an adjustment for section numbers with double figures
{\ifnum\thesection>9\relax\hspace{-1.56em}\else\hspace{-1.1em}\fi\thesection.}{.3em}{}% Adjust values to your tastes
\titlespacing{\section}%
{4.5pc}% Increase this value to have more words per line in the title
{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}%
{0.5pc}% Space between title and section text (adjust as see fit)
\begin{document}
    \section{First section} % Example 2
    \lipsum[1][1-5]
    % Bump up the section number so we can test things
    \setcounter{section}{9}
    \section{The tenth section}
    \lipsum[1][1-5]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output2]

Note that if you sections have very little text, the titles might overlap. If this happens I would suggest just adding a little extra vertical space after the text of the first section with e.g. `\vpsace{1cm}`.

Comment: The option [leftmargin] can contain only a word per line.  ButI want more than one word each line of section title and all the text of title is in hang style, as shown on my figure. Can titlesec achieve this?

Comment: For the first, definitely - the first argument of the `\titlespacing` command controls how many words you can get on 'each line'. There doesn't seem to be a native way of getting hang + leftmargin, but a simple hack should suffice - i'll edit my answer.

Comment: This works all well when the section number is less than 10. When the number(two digits) is bigger than 9, the typeset of number will extrude into the title. Then the \hspace has to be adjusted again. Is there a common way(without many times to try a new  length) to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment, I don't think titlesec provides an easy way to combine left margin with hang (I suggest you have a look through the package documentation in case you spot anything that could be useful). But I know what I would do - use an `\if` statement do add a bit more hspace if the section number is greater than 9 :).

Comment: Thank you very much for your good and valuable solutions and suggests!!

Comment: You're welcome - let me know if you need help with the `\if` statement (also: if you use my example you may want to change the final `0pc` to `0.5pc` or similar). If I've answered your question, consider accepting my answer.

Comment: \if version would be highly appreciated! I've accepted your answer.